# How to create dynamically menu in MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, menu

I'm working on a simple WPF project, using MVVM.

I want to create a menu with dynamically Items.

Its my xaml file:

```
<Menu.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding MenuText}" />
        <Setter Property="Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Image Source="{Binding MenuIcon}"
                       Height="16px"
                       Width="16px" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                Value="{Binding Children}" />

        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Menu}}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding ItemCommandParameter}"></Setter>
    </Style>

</Menu.Resources>
```

And It's the view model class that is content of my xaml file:

```
private ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> _topMenuItems;
public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> TopMenuItems
{
    get { return _topMenuItems; }
    set
    {
        if (_topMenuItems == value)
            return;

        Set("TopMenuItems", ref _topMenuItems, value);
    }
}

public void LoadMainMenu()
{
    IList<Model.MenuItemModel> fileMenuItems = PopulateFileMenuEntries();



    _topMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>();
    _topMenuItems.Add(new MenuItemModel() { MenuText = "_File", Children = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>(fileMenuItems) });
}
IList<MenuItemModel> PopulateFileMenuEntries()
{
    List<MenuItemModel> fileMenuItems = new List<MenuItemModel>();

    fileMenuItems.Add(new MenuItemModel() { MenuText = "_Theme" });
    fileMenuItems.Add(new MenuItemModel() { MenuText = "_Exit" });

    return fileMenuItems;
}
```

my Menu Item Model Class:

```
public class MenuItemModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _menuText;
    public string MenuText
    {
        get { return _menuText; }
        set
        {
            if (_menuText == value)
                return;

            Set("MenuText", ref _menuText, value);
        }
    }


    private BitmapImage _menuIcon;
    public BitmapImage MenuIcon
    {
        get { return _menuIcon; }
        set
        {
            if (_menuIcon == value)
                return;

            Set("MenuIcon", ref _menuIcon, value);
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> _children;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set
        {
            Set("Children", ref _children, value);
        }
    }

    public string ItemCommandParameter { get; set; }
}
```

My question is here:

How can I fill menu Items dynamically instead of using `PopulateFileMenuEntries` method. For example I want to have just a List Collection that is get the proper menu Items from database. How can I assign this list collection to the menu items in my sample project? I have 2 menu Items with subItems:

Main : Student, Teacher, Course,...
File : Theme, Exit,...

Comment: The usual way to populate a menu dynamically is to bind MenuItem.ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection. You seem to be doing that already. What are you trying to do? Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "dynamically"? Are you asking how to retrieve records from a database? Are you asking how to add and remove items in an ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will get idea from this

```
  <Style TargetType="expanderControl:ExpanderControl">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="expanderControl:ExpanderControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut"
                                       EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseInOut"
                                       EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="41" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Collapsed"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15"
                                                  To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"
                                                                       EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.00"
                                                                  Value="0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame"
                                                                  EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.15"
                                                                  Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1.0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition From="Expanded"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15"
                                                  To="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"
                                                                       EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="ExpandedToCollapsedKeyFrame"
                                                                  EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.00"
                                                                  Value="1" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.15"
                                                                  Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.00"
                                                                  Value="1.0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.15"
                                                                  Value="0.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"
                                                                       EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.00"
                                                                  Value="0.0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}"
                                                                  KeyTime="0:0:0.15"
                                                                  Value="-35" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="0.0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="1.0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandabilityStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expandable" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="NonExpandable">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandableContent">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="NonExpandableContent">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0"
                                                                Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ListViewItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" Background="Transparent" 
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="41" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="Header"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Grid.Row="0" />
                            <ContentControl x:Name="Expander"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Margin="11,0,0,0"
                                            Grid.Row="1" />
                            <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel"
                                  Background="Transparent"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                  />
                            <StackPanel Height="1" Background="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="NonExpandableContent"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeaderTemplate}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeader}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Canvas x:Name="ItemsCanvas"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="-120,0,0,0"
                            Opacity="0.0"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Presenter}"
                            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Presenter}">
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform TranslateY="0.0" />
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Presenter" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```